# Using Large Object in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a question regarding memory management in pyspark.

I have a large read-only dictionary, which should be queryable by each mapper in a MapReduce. This global object is very large and won't fit in the memory of each mapper.

What is the best practice for implementing this use case? My attempts have failed so far.

Thanks a lot,

Ido.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the size of the object.

- If it is much larger than memory it is better to use RDD / DataFrame and join.
- If it is reasonably small you can write it to file (for example with [`shelve`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shelve.html)) and distribute files. Spark has `SparkFiles` mechanism which can be used for that.

I have to admit that this part of your comment:

> the thing is that each mapper needs to scan the whole dictionary RDD in each iteration,

troubles me. My first recommendation in that case is to search for a better algorithm.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt answer. Actually I don't know yet the size of the dictionary, but probably it will be much larger that memory. The thing is that each mapper needs to scan the whole dictionary RDD in each iteration, and this action might cause the whole system to fail due to memory issues. The question is how should I load the graph dictionary so it will be accessible for each mapper, without having memory issues. Can you please elaborate on that? Thanks!